# why Average merge time in Hadoop yarn(2.7.1) is zero? and how to obtain precises of this time

Tags: hadoop, merge, mapreduce

I have a question about average merge time in Hadoop yarn 2.7.1
I ran a wordcount example on cluster with 7 node with a txt file (1.5GB) 
as you can see in following picture a job has 12 map task and one reduce task what Average merge time is Zero?
does this mean that **sorting or merging** of 12 map output is zero?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0I9V.png)

please guide me

Answer (score 0):

No,

Average merge time is `avg(sortFinishTime-shuffleFinishTime)`

Reducer receives input from multiple mappers during shuffle. Once the input is received, these are appended into single file at reducer(locally) and is sorted. Once sorted, reduce phase starts.

Average merge time is the average of time taken after shuffle phase and before reduce phase starts.